# how to compare two variables in <c:when>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

```
<% for(int count=0;count<lengthOfUser;count++) {%>
<%int tempuser= users[count]; %>

<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">

        <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${user.userID == tempuser}">
                   hiii
                         </c:when>

    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
<%}%>
```

This is my jsp page.I am Trying to comapare two variable.But this code is not workin.please help me.

Comment: first I think that using scriplets is not good idea. and second I want to know what is the userList variable?

Comment: userList is my arraylist from which I got resultSet From Data base.If I will try <c:when test="${user.userID == 1}"> then its work properly but when i trying to compare it with different variable.its not working.

Comment: List interface has not method with the name userId

Comment: userlist is my result set and userID is one of the field from resultSet

Comment: if i want to get info from resultSet I use this userList.getInt("userID"); where userId is the column name in db

Comment: If it works with user.userID == 1 then it means users[count] is never equal to 1. You have to find out why

Comment: i have made getter setter of it and i can able to fetch userID by user.userID but i just cant compare it with varible..

Comment: Should i use scriplet to compare tempuser to user.userID.?like <c:when test="${user.userid==<%tempuser%>}"

Comment: At first print all the values of users[count] and  user.userID to see why it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: I done with all print.i know that tempuser's value is 1 so if i put is statically its working but when i using tempuser.its not working

Comment: Are they both integers? Can't it be that you are comparing string vs integer

Comment: no Both are integer.i checked it..but one variable created from scriplet.

Answer (score 1):

All *jstl* tags will be read before any *scriptlet* tag. So, you have to create a variable using the *jstl* `<c:set` tag.
See this example :

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {%>
        <c:set value="${i}" var="tempuser1"></c:set>
        <c:set value="initialized with some value" var="tempuser2"></c:set>
        <c:out value="${tempuser1}"></c:out>
        <c:out value="${tempuser2}"></c:out>
        <br/>
        <%                            }
        %>
```

It prints in the browser :

```
initialized with some value 
initialized with some value 
initialized with some value
```

Here, `<c:out value="${tempuser1}"></c:out>` prints empty value because the variable (`i`)  declared inside the scriptlet tag doesn't exist when a *jstl* tag is read so the variable `tempuser1` (in `<c:set value="${i}" var="tempuser1"></c:set>`) is initialized with an empty value.

But, you can rewrite your code as follows, it works for me :

```
<c:forEach var="tempuser" items="users">
            <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">

                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${user.userID == tempuser}">
                        hiii
                    </c:when>

                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I have Created users array in scriplet. so can i use it in <C:foreach>?

Comment: If `users` declaration is inside the _scriptlet_ tag, then it will not work. You have to make it avaliable in any scope and create a users variable as `<c:set var="users" value="${userss}" scope="request"></c:set>`.

Comment: sir i got it. but i have arry of users. so how can i set the that value to ant  variable.please can you explain it.

Comment: Then your `int tempuser= users[count];` statement is wrong.
 
You have to initialize the users variable in your controller and add that variable in the scope using _setAttribute_ method.

If you use session.setAttribute("userss", userss);, you have to use session scope in `<c:set var="users" value="${userss}" scope="session"></c:set>`.

And also you have to use `<c:when test="${user.userID == tempuser.userID}">`.

Comment: Hi @user1487778 Please [vote for the answer and accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).